# Why does datediff return 1 day less than the actual difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following snippet of SQL:

```
Select DATEDIFF(dd, '2014-09-22 09:14:01.850','2014-09-24 17:14:53.243') -- 1
```

This returns "2", but I actually want "3", since I am calculating the total number of days attended by an employee. I.e. in the above case he has attended *3* days, but `datediff` shows 2. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Just add 1 to the result?  Is the expected answer 2 if the time on the right is _before_ the time on the left?

Comment: get the number of hours, divide by 24, and round up.

Comment: Datediff returns the number of borders passed between one value and another; in the case of days, think of the function as counting midnights.  If you want to your query to return three (one for each actual date involved), either JOIN to a calendar table, add one to the result automatically, or do the datediff in hours, divide by 24.0, and round it up the nearest whole number

Comment: @AHiggins i just added 1 to the datediff, is it ok ?

Comment: @JohnNash, if it's returning the result you want and you understand why, then yes it is ok.  Have you accounted for weekends?  Dates the employee did not work?  Shifts that cross midnight (e.g., does signing in at 11:00PM and signing out at 7:00AM count)?

Comment: yes yes, i calculated all public and usual holidays

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DATEDIFF with the `dd` parameter returns the number of date boundaries between 2 dates.

So `DATEDIFF(dd, '2014-09-22 09:14:01.850','2014-09-24 17:14:53.243')` will return 2 - because it is counting 23rd, and 24th. 
If you want to count 22nd, 23rd, and 24th, then just add 1, e.g.

```
Select DATEDIFF(dd, '2014-09-22 09:14:01.850','2014-09-24 17:14:53.243') + 1
```

Comment: Yep, it's the same reason `3 - 1 = 2` and not `3 - 1 = 3`, even though there are three numbers if you count them (1, 2, and 3).  What you're doing is subtraction, but what you're looking for is the *cardinality*.  Another way to look at it is to think of the case where the start and end is on the same date.  There are 0 days between today and today, but there was still one day involved.  That's why you need to add 1.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason `DATEDIFF(dd, ...` function calculate number of days based on 24 hours day. If there is less than 24 hours left it displays zero.

You should use only date portion of your time.

(it was an old post, but never properly answered)